# Simple GUI application

Tags: f#

I am getting to learn `F#` by editing a template application that handles event via clicks. I am trying to update a `TextBox` when a button is pressed. For now the clicks gets updated only to console.

The main goal of the question is to learn. I am going to try my best to explain my thought process and if something is wrong feel free to correct me.

**Main** :

```
open FSharpx.Control.Observable // Fsharpx

module Main =

    type State = int list

    module GuiInterface = 
        type UserAction = 
        | Zero
        | One
        | Two 
        | Three

        let observables = List.reduce Observable.merge [
            Observable.map (fun _-> Zero) Gui.btnAdd0.Click;
            Observable.map (fun _-> One) Gui.btnAdd1.Click;
            Observable.map (fun _-> Two) Gui.btnAdd2.Click;
            Observable.map (fun _-> Three) Gui.btnAdd3.Click;
        ]  

    let rec loop observable (state : State) = async{
        
        printfn "%A" state

        let! somethingObservable = Async.AwaitObservable(observable) 

        match somethingObservable with
            | GuiInterface.Zero  -> return! loop observable (0::state)
            | GuiInterface.One  -> return! loop observable (1::state)
            | GuiInterface.Two  -> return! loop observable (2::state)
            | GuiInterface.Three  -> return! loop observable (3::state)
            | _  -> failwith "Not implemented yet!"
    }

    Async.StartImmediate(loop GuiInterface.observables []); System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Gui.form)
```

---

**Gui** :

```
module Gui = 
    open System.Windows.Forms

    let form = new Form(Text="FSharpx", TopMost=true)
    let btnAdd0 = new Button(Text="Add 0")
    let btnAdd1 = new Button(Text="Add 1", Top=20)
    let btnAdd2 = new Button(Text="Add 2", Top=40)
    let btnAdd3 = new Button(Text="Add 3", Top=60)
    let display = new TextBox(Text="click the buttons", Width=200, Left=200)

    form.Controls.AddRange [| btnAdd0 ; btnAdd1; btnAdd2; btnAdd3; display |]
```

---

In the `let observables` I think it transforms the click into whatever value that we have in the type for user actions. Then it mergers them all together.

The `observable` waits for input as in when the user clicks and then does a conversion from the `GuiInterface` type to whatever the logic of the program is.

As stated I dont know how I would handle instead of printing the list to the console do the same thing but for the `TextBox`. I know the list contains int and that it needs to be converted to string.

Comment: Really as Tomas said you need to try something like Avalonia.FuncUI for gui apps, it has either Elmish or Component-based architecture with composable DSL for gui.

Comment: I will look into it, but this was a template provided to me so I can learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert the list to string, you can use `sprintf`. You could just replace your current `printf` statement with the following assignment:

```
Gui.display.Text <- sprintf "%A" state
```

This works, but it may be a bit too imperative and it tightly couples the GUI with the logic - fine for learning, but probably not a very good practice. An alternative would be to define a new event (observable) and communicate the text updates via that:

```
type State = int list

module GuiInterface = 
  type UserAction = Zero | One | Two | Three

  let observables = List.reduce Observable.merge [
      Observable.map (fun _-> Zero) Gui.btnAdd0.Click;
      Observable.map (fun _-> One) Gui.btnAdd1.Click;
      Observable.map (fun _-> Two) Gui.btnAdd2.Click;
      Observable.map (fun _-> Three) Gui.btnAdd3.Click;
  ]  

  let stateChange = new Event<_>()

let rec loop observable (state : State) = async{
    GuiInterface.stateChange.Trigger(sprintf "%A" state)
    let! somethingObservable = Async.AwaitObservable(observable) 
    match somethingObservable with
    | GuiInterface.Zero  -> return! loop observable (0::state)
    | GuiInterface.One  -> return! loop observable (1::state)
    | GuiInterface.Two  -> return! loop observable (2::state)
    | GuiInterface.Three  -> return! loop observable (3::state)
    | _  -> failwith "Not implemented yet!"
}

GuiInterface.stateChange.Publish.Add(fun s ->
  Gui.display.Text <- s)
Async.StartImmediate(loop GuiInterface.observables [])
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Gui.form)
```

However, you can also replace your loop with the `Observable.scan` function that lets you maintain state and update it depending on other events:

```
type State = int list

module GuiInterface = 
  type UserAction = Zero | One | Two | Three

  let observables = List.reduce Observable.merge [
      Observable.map (fun _-> Zero) Gui.btnAdd0.Click;
      Observable.map (fun _-> One) Gui.btnAdd1.Click;
      Observable.map (fun _-> Two) Gui.btnAdd2.Click;
      Observable.map (fun _-> Three) Gui.btnAdd3.Click;
  ]  

  let stateChanged = 
    observables 
    |> Observable.scan (fun state update ->
      match update with
      | Zero -> (0::state)
      | One -> (1::state)
      | Two -> (2::state)
      | Three -> (3::state)
      | _  -> failwith "Not implemented yet!") []
    |> Observable.map (sprintf "%A")

GuiInterface.stateChanged.Add(fun s ->
  Gui.display.Text <- s)
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Gui.form)
```

That said, if you are seriously interested in UI development in a functional way in F#, it is probably better to look at [Elmish](https://elmish.github.io/elmish/), which is a set of nice functional abstractions - and is much nicer to use than Windows Forms.